# Display html pages based on Roles in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, I have the below code:

```
$scope.roleId = localStorage.getItem("Role ID");
```

In my application I am having 2 HTML pages, I am storing the role ID in local storage, based on role Id I have to display the HTML page any solution for this And this `roleId` will be changed based on logged in user

Can I try using `if else` conditions in my controller like below, I am not getting how to achive this

```
if ($scope.roleId==2) {

}
```

Comment: A more detailed description of what you want to filter based on these role would help .... elements, templates, routes?

Comment: @charlietfl i am working on Hospital management poc in this application based on roledID i have to display the particular html page,for doctor doctor.html and for patient patient.html. for doctor roleId will be 1 and for patient roleId will be 2 based on this roled i have to display particular page.

Comment: Can set a `resolve` on routes in router that depends on roles. What router are you using? If it's ui-router set a parent state for each role and then all child states can't be accessed if parent resolve gets rejected

Comment: I got solution by using ng-include    <div class="row"  ng-show="roleId ==2" ng-include="'app/components/dashBoard/dashboard1.html'">
      
      </div>

Comment: probably want `ng-if` so template never even loads or use dynamically set `src`. Suggest looking into resolve though since `ng-show` isn't very scaleable

Comment: @charlietfl what will be the difference between using ng-if and ng-show in my case

Comment: one only hides the html...the other doesn't render it at all

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create states according to role id's, I am putting example using some dummy data-

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider
                .otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
                .state('role_1', {
                    url: '/role_1',
                    templateUrl: 'role_1.html',
                    controller: 'userCtrl'
                })
                .state('role_2', {
                    url: '/role_2',
                    templateUrl: 'role_2.html',
                    controller: 'userCtrl'
                })
                .state('access_denied', {
                    url: '/access_denied',
                    templateUrl: '403.html'
                })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }]);
```

Now these states will be route according to user role id.

We have to write code in .run method which is like following -

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, $window, localStorageService, $cookies) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var roleId = localStorageService.get('roleId');

        if (roleId !== undefined && roleId == 1) {
            $location.url("/role_1");
        } else if (roleId !== undefined && roleId == 2) {
            $location.url("/role_2");
        } else {
            $location.url("/access_denied");
        }


    });
});
```

I think it will solve your problem, please update your code accordingly

Thanks